# Create a trigger which increments an id if it isn't specified

Tags: mysql, triggers

When I insert a row in my table I want the id to behave like AUTO_INCREMENT if the id wasn't specified. I gave it a shot trying to do it with a trigger but i can't make it work. It always tries to set the id to 0. This is my attempt:

```
CREATE TRIGGER inc_id BEFORE INSERT ON project
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN    
    DECLARE new_id integer;
    IF NEW.id is null THEN
       SELECT MAX(a.id)+1 INTO new_id FROM (SELECT id FROM project UNION SELECT 0 id) a;
       SET NEW.id = new_id;
    END IF;
END
```

I then try to insert a row with:

```
INSERT INTO project(projekt) VALUES("test")
```

I also tried with:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id),0)+1 INTO new_id FROM project
```

This is a more simple select but the problem persists.

Comment: Why so such complicated SELECT? Wouldn't this work? `SELECT MAX(id)+1 INTO new_id FROM project`

Comment: @marki555 Not if it's empty

Comment: @Marki555 I don't think so as MAX(id) returned NULL when there were no rows

Comment: This will fail miserably when multiple threads insert at the same time. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Vatev ok, it won't be very frequent requests but of course it's bad anyways if it's not thrad-safe. What do you mean? I'm trying to accomplish what i described. My primary key consists of two columns where one is id. If the id isn't specified it's a new item and it should take the id next in line.

Comment: If you don't want to have gaps in the IDs the only way is to have the transactions which insert records to run in serial. If gaps in IDs are acceptable just use AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: @Vatev The thing is that i want several rows to have the same id. That's why I only want to increment it if it isn't specified. The rows with the same id's will have diffrent value in the other column which is part of the primary key.

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT works as a default value for the field, if you specify a value it will be used instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by just using AUTO_INCREMENT. Apparently it works as a default.